# Create a SpecificRecord from an Avro Schema programmatically

Tags: avro

I'm working with the following code that takes a `org.apache.avro.Schema` and returns a `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord`.

How can I change it to return a `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord` instead?

```
  private GenericRecord generateRecord(Schema schema) {
    GenericRecordBuilder builder = new GenericRecordBuilder(schema);
    for (Schema.Field field : schema.getFields()) {
      builder.set(field, generateObject(field.schema()));
    }
    return builder.build();
  }
```

e.g.

```
if (schema.getName().equals("MyCustomRecord")) {
    // code to create SpecificRecord here from Schema
}
```

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Comment: Nope, gave up looking